# Inner product of the sequence space $l^{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ are two sequences of real numbers. If both $\Sigma a_{n}^{2}$ and $\Sigma b_{n}^{2}$ converge, we deduce by Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality that $(\Sigma_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}b_{k})^{2}\leq(\Sigma a_{i}^{2})(\Sigma b_{j}^{2})$ holds for every $n$, then how to show $\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{k}b_{k}$ converges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that ($\sum_{k=m}^na_kb_k)^2 \leq \sum_{k=m}^n a_k^2\sum_{k=m}^n b_k^2.$
Since both sums on the right can be bounded above (for $m$ sufficiently large) [by convergence hypothesis] same is true of the sum on the left.

Answer (score 4):

What you wrote is valid but unnecessary.
Since $(|a_k|-|b_k|)^2 \geq 0$, $|a_k|^2+|b_k|^2=a_k^2+b_k^2\geq 2|a_k b_k|$ and $|a_k b_k| \leq (a_k^2+b_k^2)/2$.  Since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k^2$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k^2$ converge, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k b_k$ converges absolutely by the Comparison Test.

Comment: It's a nice proof! I ask this question because I met problem while reading textbooks. I want to know how to do the proof with Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality (some authors adopt this way).

Answer (score 0):

You should use Cauchy's criterion in the real numbers:

By Cauchy-Schwarz, you have $(\sum_{k=N}^M a_kb_k)^2 \leq (\sum_{k=N}^M a_k^2)(\sum_{k=N}^M b_k^2)$, which shows that $LHS$ is arbitrary small for large $N$ and $M > N$.